# Source variables and values in file

Tags: bash

I have file with next content

```
var1=(val1 val2 var3)
var2=(val4 val5 var6)
```

and source it within bash script with dot (.) then I could access `var1[0]`, `var2[2]` etc but I should know `var1` and `var2`

Is it there a way to get `var?` to parse dynamically the file, despite of number of var's or their names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the difference between all variables set before and after sourcing the script.

```
before=""  # set before to exclude
before=$(compgen -v)
. filewithnextcontent
compgen -v | comm -13 <(cat <<<"$before") -
```

Comment: That's not the goal

Comment: @Topper, _How_ is it not the goal? You want to know which variables the file provides. Comparing the before and after set accomplishes as much. It may not accomplish it the way you intended, but tough cookies; you need to use non-shell tools if your goal is to get an AST; in native shell (which is to say, without using something like the Haskell-based shell parser written by koalaman for shellcheck), this is as close as you can get.

Comment: (The other answer works fine too, but it's not in any sense parsing the file, since it's just listing all variables matching a pattern -- just as `compgen -v` does, for that matter, if you tell it to match against a prefix).

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that specific -v option of compgen. Tested and works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.  One possibility is that after sourcing the file containing the variable definitions you want to get a list of the variables that have just been defined.  One way to do that may be to use the `"${!prefix@}"` expansion, described in the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) section of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).  It expands to the names of the variables whose names begin with `prefix`.  In this case, assuming that all of the variables defined in the file begin with `var` you could use `"${!var@}"`.  For example, assuming that the assignments in the question are in the file `vars.bash`, this Bash program

```
#! /bin/bash -p

source vars.bash

for v in "${!var@}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$v"
done
```

prints

```
var1
var2
```

Comment: Ok folks, I could did not explain correctly the goal. I've receiving regular files. Must use inside val's (val1, val2, val3) but depends from the process wich send to my script files - varX= could vary. I don't know what var could arrive.
var=(123 abc 111)
dump=(sample level1 level2)
next time
var123=(888 777 aaa)

now i'm parsing it with sed bud there should be more sofisticated way. That's why I'm asking.